# Calculate percentage in groups in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

Is there a convenient way to calculate percentage of each item in a group in DolphinDB?

For example:

```
groupID x  percentage
1       1  0.25
1       1  0.25
1       2  0.5
2       4  0.2
2       6  0.3
2       10 0.5
```

In kdb, I can write one line of code with `fby`. I am wondering if there is a similar way to do it in DolphinDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL extension `context by` in dolphindb:

```
select groupID, x, x\sum(x) as percentage from t context by groupID
```